# How can I find my lost iPhone 5c?

Tags: iphone

I lost my iPhone 5c in Gypsom, Colorado and am pretty sure it has 50% or more of battery remaining.

How can i locate it?

Comment: Start by calling your number. If a honest person found it they will answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Find My iPhone enabled on the device, go to [icloud.com](http://icloud.com/) and see if the device is online. If it is, you can locate it on a map and put it in lost mode to track the location as well as send a message to it.